How to Draw a Horizontal Line on TradingView Based on the Highest Volume Day in the Last 200 Days?
"I want to draw a horizontal line on a TradingView chart. The process is as follows:
Identify the date with the highest trading volume in the past 200 days.
Find the high price on that date.
Draw a horizontal line at that high price, extending from that date to the current date."

What have you tried? This is not a coding service :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
